# How to extract file name from the uploaded file/form with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

The following data is uploaded to my GAE application -

[image: Picasa upload data]

How can I

1. get fields with files only
2. get filenames of the uploaded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get fields with files only

   ```
   import cgi

   values = self.request.POST.itervalues()
   files = [v for v in values if isinstance(v, cgi.FieldStorage)]
   ```
2. get filenames of the uploaded files

   ```
   filenames = [f.filename for f in files]
   ```

**Edit:** corrected snippet, now tested :)

Comment: moraes, I am getting 'not indexable' error: `File "/base/data/home/apps/picasa2vkontakte/1.352422470709739983/picasa2vkontakte.py", line 138, in post
    files_arguments.extend(v for v in values if isinstance(v, cgi.FieldStorage))`

Comment: Thanks, moraes. If I use this approach, how can I get size of the uploaded file? `for single_file in files: len(single_file)/(1024.0*1024.0)` returns `not indexable` error. And how to get content of the file to have it stored in datastore? `photo_file.file = db.Blob(single_file)`? (can not find any docs about files and their properties like .filename)

Comment: They are FieldStorage instances, so `contents = single_file.value`. Get len of contents then. Docs: http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/cgi.FieldStorage-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is POSTed using a form, for #2, see [Get original filename google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004476/get-original-filename-google-app-engine)

For #1, you could iterate through the self.request.POST multidict and see anything that looks like a file.  self.request.POST looks like this:

UnicodeMultiDict([(u'file_1', FieldStorage(u'file_1', u'filename_1')), (u'random_string_field', u'random_string_value')])

Hope that helps you out

-Sam

Comment: _see anything that looks like a file_ - the question is how to identify that ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = self.request.POST['file'].filename
file_ext = self.request.POST['file'].type
```

**OR**

```
filename = self.request.params[<form element name with file>].filename
```