# Get uploaded file name (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to get the name of the uploaded file in my GAE app. Currently when I run

```
self.request.get('file')
```

I only get the contents of the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004476/get-original-filename-google-app-engine

Comment: basically  self.request.params[<form element name with file>].filename

Answer (score 2):

```
img = request.files['image']
print("Name of Image", img.filename)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64798436/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.